# Timming processing time to deal with requests per minute limits when interacting with 3rd party API

Tags: python

So, the 3rd party charges differently for certain limits values. Let's just say I'm cheap and don't wanna pay the full rate for unlimited access.

The approach I've used is rather simple, I just call sleep for 3 seconds after processing each request (paid for the 20 calls per minute plan).

Here is some clipped code for illustration:

```
import requests
import sqlite3
from time import sleep

timetosleep = 3
conn = sqlite3.connection('db.db')
c = conn.cursor()
keys = [
    "A BIG LIST, SOMETHING LIKE len == 80K" #working with 500 at a time
]

def treatResponse(response):
    #series of validations, some regex and stuff
    returns "A TUPLE WITH DATA TO THE SQLITE DB"

for key in keys:
    response = requests.get("API ADDRESS AND KEYS", {"auth":"auth"})
    #if response is GREAT! yadayada
    c.execute(
           """INSERT INTO tbl(field1, field2) values(?, ?)""",
              treatResponse(response.json()))
    conn.commit()
    sleep(timetosleep)
```

As the function used to treat the response is rather expensive, with a bunch of sequential regex calls, and the server may get a long time (relative to the limit/minute) to respond, it may be an overkill to wait 3 full seconds (or even to wait at all).

Does anyone has a solution for timing each iteration?
If this operation is done neatly, it could be used to reduce the sleep timer and improve performance by a lot. TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe set your `for` loop to iterate with the max threshold rather than explicitly wait:

```
for key in keys:
    start = time.time()
    response = requests.get("API ADDRESS AND KEYS", {"auth:auth"})
    #if response is GREAT! yadayada
    c.execute(
           """INSERT INTO tbl(field1, field2) values(?, ?)""",
              treatResponse(response.json()))
    conn.commit()

    timetosleep = 3. - (time.time()-start)
    if timetosleep<0:
        continue
    sleep(timetosleep)
```

That way, if your functions take more than 3 seconds, it doesn't sleep, otherwise it will wait the remaining time

Answer (score 1):

Since `requests.get` will force python to wait for its' completion, you can accomplish this by recording the time before you make the response, and checking how much time has passed before you sleep:

```
import time
# Code omitted for brevity
for key in keys:
    start = time.time() # Start time

    ################ TIME THIS BLOCK ################
    response = requests.get("API ADDRESS AND KEYS", {"auth:auth"})
    #if response is GREAT! yadayada
    c.execute(
       """INSERT INTO tbl(field1, field2) values(?, ?)""",
          treatResponse(response.json()))
    conn.commit()
    #################################################

    end = time.time()
    print(end - start) # Time in seconds that have passed
    if end - start < 3 :
        sleep(3 - (end - start))
```

Comment: Both responses are essentially the same, but C.Nivis's treatment on the timing is nicer. Thanks anyway.